# MS Access extracting elements from multi-valued field based on condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, multivalue

I get a report where there is a multi-valued field that houses user roles and the respective user information. There are a total of 6 roles and each row of data could have multiple people operating under the same role. I am using MS Access 2013 to do my data manipulation.

```
ID  Data    Users
1   Data1   Supervisor (MICROSOFT OUTLOOK; microsoftoutlook@example.com 9999999999) Admin Assistant (WATER BOTTLE; waterbottle@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 999999999)
2   Data2   Supervisor (COMPUTER MONITOR; computermonitor@example.com; 9999999999) Admin Assistant (MICROSOFT EXCEL; microsoftexcel@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 999999999); Analyst (ORANGE PURPLE; orangepurple@example.com; 999999991)
3   Data3   Supervisor (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 9999999999) Admin (MICROSOFT ACCESS; microsoftaccess@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (ORANGE PURPLE; orangepurple@example.com; 999999999); Analyst (YELLOW BLACK; yellowblack@example.com; 999999991)
```

The above is a truncated and substituted data set. In ID = 2 and 3, there are 2 analysts. There could be a case where there are 2 "Admin Assistants". The formatting for the `Users` is exactly as listed. Individual users could be listed across multiple rows as well and under different roles sometimes.

I don't necessarily need to split the data apart, but I do need pick out certain roles based on the `Data` column. If `Data` = [Certain Condition], then pull in a certain user role. For example, if `Data` = "Completed", I need to pull all the "Supervisors" for that row. If `Data` = "In progress", I need to pull all the "Analysts" for that row. There are other conditionals too for determining which role and users to pull. I need to pull both the user role and the users associated with that role for that row. I would like to create 2 new columns for "Ownership Role" and "Current Ownership". "Ownership Role" is the User Role and "Current Ownership" should contain all the users associated with that role for that row.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need any clarification. I appreciate you taking the time to read this.

UPDATE

My desired results are below.

```
ID  Data    Ownership Role  Current Ownership   Users
1   Completed   Supervisor  MICROSOFT OUTLOOK   Supervisor (MICROSOFT OUTLOOK; microsoftoutlook@example.com 9999999999) Admin Assistant (WATER BOTTLE; waterbottle@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 999999999)
2   In Progress Analyst GREEN BLUE, ORANGE PURPLE   Supervisor (COMPUTER MONITOR; computermonitor@example.com; 9999999999) Admin Assistant (MICROSOFT EXCEL; microsoftexcel@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 999999999); Analyst (ORANGE PURPLE; orangepurple@example.com; 999999991)
3   Initiated   Admin   MICROSOFT ACCESS    Supervisor (GREEN BLUE; greenblue@example.com; 9999999999) Admin (MICROSOFT ACCESS; microsoftaccess@example.com, 9999999999) Analyst (ORANGE PURPLE; orangepurple@example.com; 999999999); Analyst (YELLOW BLACK; yellowblack@example.com; 999999991)
```

UPDATE 2019-05-10
Due to my failure to properly explain the question and set up a sample data set, I am posting the cases based on June7's answer and a sample row of data.

```
Case "Initiated"
    strRole = "Main Admin Assistant"
Case "Drafted"
    strRole = "Financial Analyst"
Case "Rated"
    strRole = "Contractor Rep"
Case "Reviewed"
    strRole = "Assessing Official"
Case "Finalized"
    strRole = "Reviewing Official"
```

Sample Data - this is all in 1 cell in Excel and each element is on a different line in that cell. Immediately after the close parenthesis, there is NO space from what I can tell so the next user role begins IMMEDIATELY.

```
Supervisor (ERGO KB; ergokb@example.com; (999) 999-9999)Team Lead (WIDE SCREEN; widescreen@example.com; 9999999999)Team Rep (CELL PHONE; cellphone@example.com; 999-999-9999)Team Rep (CLICK PEN; clickpen@example.com; (999) 999-9999)Main Admin Assistant (WIRED MOUSE; wiredmouse@example.com; 999-999-9999)Main Admin Assistant (PHONE CHARGER; phonecharger@example.com; 9999999999)Financial Analyst (WATER BOTTLE; waterbottle@example.com; (999) 999-9999)Financial Analyst (CLEAR TAPE; cleartape@example.com; 999-999-9999)Human Resources (POST IT NOTE; postitnote@example.com; 999-999-9999)
```

For each status below, I want the associated User Role.

```
Status      User Role
Initiated   Main Admin Assistant
Drafted     Financial Analyst
Rated       Team Rep
Reviewed    Financial Analyst
Finalized   Human Resources
Completed   Completed
```

Real Desired Results

```
Status      User Role               Users
Initiated   Main Admin Assistant    WIRED MOUSE, PHONE CHARGER
Drafted     Financial Analyst       WATER BOTTLE, CLEAR TAPE
Rated       Team Rep                CELL PHONE, CLICK PEN
Reviewed    Financial Analyst       WATER BOTTLE, CLEAR TAPE
Finalized   Human Resources         POST IT NOTE
Completed   Completed               Completed
```

Comment: What does it mean to "pull in all the supervisors" what would the output of that be? The information for a `Supervisor` that is contained inside the parantheses? Just the email address? The entire `user` column contents if it contains at least one `supervisor`? You say you don't necessarily need to split, but I get the feeling that you do to get your desired results. Perhaps you could share your desired results of your example query `SELECT <something from the user column FROM yourtable WHERE data=[certain condition]`

Comment: @JNevill thank you for your reply. I have updated my original post to include the desired results. I added in values for the "Data" column as well. There are other columns which I did not include, but it is not needed for this logic as far as I know. Based on the value in the `Data` column, I would like the name of the user(s) for that particular role. If it's multiple users, I would like them separated by a comma and a space. `SELECT ID, Data, IF(Data="Completed", SUPERVISOR_NAMES, IF(Data="In Progress", ANALYST_NAMES, IF(Data="Initiated", ADMIN_NAMES)))` That would be the pseudo logic.

Comment: Where does one derive "Owner" = "Supervisor" and "In Progress" = "Analyst". Is there a second table that holds this relationship, or is that relationship to be defined in this SQL you need to write using an `Iif()`?

Comment: It's based on data in another column. There are 6 possible conditions which will determine which User Role should be used. It's not housed in another table, but just a nested "if" statement. So if "Completed" then display the Supervisor, if "In Progress", display the analysts.

Comment: I could create another table with those conditions and relationships with 6 rows if that is easier or a better practice. I appreciate you taking the time to assist me.

Comment: So is that actually an Access multi-value field or just a simple text field with a string of multiple data elements?

Comment: It is a simple text field with a string of multiple data elements. I did not know there was an actual multi-value field within Access. This report comes out of a system in .xlsx format. @June7

Comment: Data sample show words Supervisor, Analyst, Admin but you say you want 'all the supervisors' - so are there actually names in that string? You want to pull names? It would be simple to calculate Role based on Data but if you want names pulled from that string, that will likely require VBA function that parses string. Possibly include manipulating array or collection object.

Comment: Correct, there may be an instance where there could be multiple people associated with one role. "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK", "GREEN BLUE", "ORANGE PURPLE", and "MICROSOFT ACCESS" are all the names of the individuals. "GREEN BLUE" and "ORANGE PURPLE" are both "Analysts". The format is: `[User Role] (FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME; [e-mail]; [phone_number])`. If you look at my desired output on the second row of data, you will see both Analysts listed separately. Got it, I was hoping it was possible within SQL. Any good starting point or logic on how to accomplish that? I appreciate your time @June7!

Comment: Revised info shows shows different roles in Case and association list - which is correct?

Comment: Why is Financial Analyst twice in the association list? The sample data shows both "Team Lead" and "Team Rep". "Supervisor" is not in the list or case but it is in the data sample. Your info is still messed up.

Comment: The updated role and association list is correct. Financial Analyst is associated with 2 cases since I am trying to figure out who has ownership of the current action. That is correct, there are user roles which are in the data which are NOT used for this particular purpose. Down the line I may need to extract the "Team Lead", "Team Rep", and "Supervisor" just for visibility into all the users in the database. However, that is not needed at this point and I don't want to bug you about it now since you have already taken a lot of time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency in structure is critical when parsing strings. For instance, there is a semi-colon after ) between the last two elements of IDs 2 and 3 but no semi-colon after the others. That extra semi-colon complicates programming logic. Since comments say that semi-colon is a typo as well as no space following ), code reflects those corrections in structure.

Here is a function to get you started. Place this procedure in a general module and it can be called from query or textbox.

```
Function GetUsers(strData As String, strUsers As String) As String
Dim aryS As Variant, x As Integer, strRole As String, strNames As String
aryS = Split(strUsers, ")")
Select Case strData
    Case "Initiated"
        strRole = "Main Admin Assistant"
    Case "Drafted"
        strRole = "Financial Analyst"
    Case "Rated"
        strRole = "Team Rep"
    Case "Reviewed"
        strRole = "Financial Analyst"
    Case "Finalized"
        strRole = "Human Resources"
End Select
For x = 0 To UBound(aryS) - 1
    If strRole = Left(aryS(x), InStr(aryS(x), "(") - 2) Then
        strNames = strNames & Mid(aryS(x), InStr(aryS(x), "(") + 1, InStr(aryS(x), ";") - 1 - InStr(aryS(x), "(")) & ", "
    End If
Next
If strNames <> "" Then GetUsers = Left(strNames, Len(strNames) - 2)
End Function
```

Instead of determining Role by calculation with Data, suggest a table that defines these associations. Include that table in query then pass the Role to function instead of Data and the Case block should not be needed.

Revised code to deal with inconsistent phone number structure that sometimes has parens causing previous code to fail as well as the possibility of similar role names (I probably should have gone this way to begin with):

```
Function GetUsers(strData As String, strUsers As String) As String
Dim strRole As String, strNames As String
Select Case strData
    Case "Initiated"
        strRole = "Main Admin Assistant ("
    Case "Drafted"
        strRole = "Financial Analyst ("
    Case "Rated"
        strRole = "Team Rep ("
    Case "Reviewed"
        strRole = "Financial Analyst ("
    Case "Finalized"
        strRole = "Human Resources ("
    Case "Completed"
        strRole = "Financial Analyst Jr ("
End Select
Do While InStr(strUsers, strRole) > 0
    strUsers = Mid(strUsers, InStr(strUsers, strRole))
    strNames = strNames & Mid(strUsers, InStr(strUsers, "(") + 1, InStr(strUsers, ";") - Len(strRole) - 1) & ", "
    strUsers = Mid(strUsers, 2)
Loop
If strNames <> "" Then GetUsers = Left(strNames, Len(strNames) - 2)
End Function
```

Comment: I apologize! Every element between the parentheses will be separated by a semicolon (;) always. I am going to do my best to start understanding your code right there since that is above my current level. I really appreciate it and I have a feeling I should create a new question if I have any more questions. @June7

Comment: You show comma and semi-colon separating elements within the parens (so the commas are typo errors?). It's the oddball semi-colon outside the parens that is the issue.

Comment: That was also a mistake. This is exactly what it will look like:
`UserRole (FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME; email_address; phone_number)UserRole (FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME; email_address; phone_number)` So after the UserRole there will be a space and open parenthesis, each element is separated by a semicolon and a space, then a close parenthesis, and immediately with no spaces the next UserRole.

Comment: There is also a space between the FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME, but it should be considered as one element. Got it! I am going to test it out as now then.

Comment: Wow! That really worked very well! I really really appreciate that! I am going to try to figure out how to implement this on the table now. Since the "Completed" is stored in another column and I use a PowerShell script to execute my queries and now I can use it to execute that piece of VBA code too I believe.

Comment: Oh I see! So like `SELECT GetUsers(s.Data, s.Users) FROM tbl_status s` Thanks, I will mark it since it's working on the test data.

Comment: Sorry! Thought I clicked both of them. :) There we go. I really appreciate it @June7. You resolved that very quickly. I believe I understand the logic behind your code, now I will study the syntax for future use. I've learned so much from the people here who take the time to answer my questions and explain concepts. Thank you again, you have really saved me!

Comment: I hate to bother you, but I have two issues I am encountering. I am getting a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" on the `GetUsers = Left(strNames, Len(strNames) - 2)` line. Does it matter if my `Ownership Role` has 2 words like "Admin Assistant"? I also need to make if `Data` = "On Hold", display "On Hold" for `CurrentOwnership`. I have been trying logically by using `Nz` and `IIf` statements, but I can't seem to get it. If it complicates things too much, I can find a work around. Everything else is functioning as needed though.

Comment: `Case "Completed"
    strRole = "Supervisor"
Case "In Progress"
    strRole = "Analyst"
Case "Other"
    strRole = "Admin Assistant"
Case "On Hold"
    strRole = "Analyst"
`

Here is my test:
`("Other", "Supervisor (BOB BOTTLE; bob@bottle.com; 9999999999)Analyst (WHITE BOARD; white@board.com; 9999999999)Admin Assistant (PHONE CHARGER; phone@charger.com; 9999999999)"`

Comment: You show Analyst twice, only the first will match. Should one be "Admin"? You said there were 6 conditions but you code for only 4. The error is probably because there are no names returned. No, space is not issue. However, the InStr() test will match "Admin" with "Admin Assistant" which I did not account for. Rats! See revised answer.

Comment: If you don't want names for "On Hold" then why do you show a Case option? Don't call the function if data is "On Hold". Expression in query: `IIf([Data]="On Hold", "On Hold", GetUsers(…))`

Comment: I was trying to make it simpler so I could learn from it, but I clearly failed and just made it more complicated. I am not sure if it's better to just post a new question at this point or how much change would be needed, but I updated my original question at the bottom to include the exact cases and a sample data set which I have triple checked.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: I will be able to test it out on Monday! Thank you!

Comment: The code will now fail because of the ) after the area code in phone number. It wasn't there in the original data sample.

Comment: I did not realize it until I looked at more of the data. I captured the different ways the phone numbers are listed now in that sample data. Well I really botched things up in this question :).

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: I just checked it and it's pulling like it should be! I promise this is the last thing and then this task is completed. If there is "Financial Analyst Jr" and just "Financial Analyst", would that require a significant code or logic modification? When I tested that (I know I did not state it originally), it was pulling both "Financial Analyst" and "Financial Analyst Jr" with a couple extra characters. Everything else is working perfectly in the query and no errors thrown. I don't know how to thank you enough!

Comment: The "Completed" case should go to the "Financial Analyst Jr". So I would not want the "Financial Analyst" to be pulled in. I changed "CLEAR TAPE" in my sample data to a "Financial Analyst Jr". I also just tried it with a few others adding "Jr" or "Temp" or other words after "Team Rep", "Human Resources", etc. and it looked like it was matching that sub-string and if there was, it would pull in the data. There may be cases like that. If the exact word matters, let me know and I will dig through and find it. This really is the last bit, I validated everything else and it works perfectly.

Comment: Need to get your parameters settled. You have now changed the requirements for "Completed" twice. See revised answer, again.

Comment: It is 100% functioning and I am extremely sorry for all the changes. I truly appreciate the time and effort you put in to helping me. I know it was extremely frustrating with all the changes. Thank you for your patience and assistance!